# Error during inference: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'DecodeJpeg' with these attrs

Tags: android, tensorflow

I got this error message when I ran the app. It crash just a few seconds after app launched.

```
05-28 09:05:29.791 15453-15472/my.xxxxx.androidtensorflowbirdexample A/native: tensorflow_jni.cc:304 Error during inference: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'DecodeJpeg' with these attrs
                                                                                     [[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false](DecodeJpeg/contents)]]
05-28 09:05:29.791 15453-15472/my.xxxxx.androidtensorflowbirdexample A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 15472 (InferenceThread)

                                                                                [ 05-28 09:05:29.796 15453:15503 E/         ]
                                                                                [android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 1620


                                                                                [ 05-28 09:05:29.796 15453:15503 E/         ]
                                                                                [android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 1620
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the output graph to optimized graph or quantized graph.

First, build the appropriate tools for the conversion:

For optimized graph,

```
bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:optimize_for_inference
```

For quantized graph,

```
bazel build tensorflow/tools/quantization:quantize_graph
```

And then, convert you retrained graph to the desired format:

retrained -> optimized

```
tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference \
--input=train/output/flower_photos/retrained_graph.pb \
--output=train/output/flower_photos/optimized_graph.pb \
--input_names=Mul \
--output_names=final_result
```

optimized -> quantized

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/quantization/quantize_graph \
--input=train/output/flower_photos/optimized_graph.pb \
--output=train/output/flower_photos/rounded_graph.pb \
--output_node_names=final_result \
--mode=weights_rounded
```

you have to use appropriate graph name you have and input/output node names can be different if you created the graph from scratch

For more information, please refer to: 
https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/
(it's a little bit outdated, but you can get great overview of the android implementation)

Comment: i will try it first.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you Android version or the mobile  CPU does not support the Tensorflow JNI library. You may want to check both your Android version and your mobile CPU.

Comment: It's not about JNI. It's about tensorflow modelling. I need to retrain again without DecodeJpeg attribute.